# C# How does the method indexOfTop(int stackNum) determine the top of the stack?

Tags: c#, stack

How does the method "indexOfTop(int stackNum)" accurately calculates the top of the the given stack number?

Source: Cracking the Coding Interview 189 Programming Questions & Solutions : Chapter 3 | Stacks and Queues : 3.1 - Describe how you could use a single array to implement three stacks.

```
class FixedMultiStack
{
    private int numberOfStacks = 3;
    private int stackCapacity;
    private int[] values;
    private int[] sizes;

    public FixedMultiStack(int stackSize)
    {
        stackCapacity = stackSize;
        values = new int[stackSize * numberOfStacks];
        sizes = new int[numberOfStacks];
    }
    public void push(int stackNum, int value)
    {
        if (isFull(stackNum)) throw new Exception("Full stack, cannot push.");
        /* Increment stack pionter and then update top value. */
        sizes[stackNum]++;
        values[indexOfTop(stackNum)] = value;
    }
    public int pop(int stackNum)
    {
        if (isEmpty(stackNum)) throw new Exception("Empty Stack, nothing to pop.");
        int topIndex = indexOfTop(stackNum);
        int value = values[topIndex];   //Get Top.
        values[topIndex] = 0;           //Clear
        sizes[stackNum]--;              //Shrink
        return value;

    }
    /* Return top element. */
    public int peek(int stackNum)
    {
        if (isEmpty(stackNum)) throw new Exception("Empty Stack, nothing to peek at.");
        return values[indexOfTop(stackNum)];
    }
    public bool isFull(int stackNum)
    {
        return sizes[stackNum] == stackCapacity;
    }
    public bool isEmpty(int stackNum)
    {
        return sizes[stackNum] == 0;
    }
    /* Returns index of the top of the stack. */
    private int indexOfTop(int stackNum)
    {
        int offset = stackNum * stackCapacity;
        int size = sizes[stackNum];
        return offset + size - 1;
    }*
}
```

Comment: It maintains a `int[] sizes` array that keeps track of the size of that stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top of the code fragment, we read:

```
private int[] sizes;
```

This is an array that - for each of the three stacks - keeps track of the amount of elements for that stack. If we push on a certain stack, than the `sizes[stackNum]` is incremented.

Now the layout of the stacks is:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|A|A|a|a|B|b|b|b|C|C|C|c|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

with `a` the places reserved for the first stack, `b` the places reserved for the second stack, and `c` the places reserved for the third one. We know that stack `stackNum` begins at `stackNum * stackCapacity` (mind that `stackNum` starts with `0` for the first stack). So by adding the number of occupied places, we obtain the index of the top of the stack.

In the example, I used uppercase `A`/`B`/`C` to denote occupied places. So here `sizes` will be `{2,1,3}`. If we thus query for the top of stack `b`, we ask `indexOfTop(1)`. Now since every stack (in our example) uses four spaces, our offset is thus located at `4*1 == 4`. Since there is one element on the stack, the offset is at `4*1+1-1` so `4`.

Note that if no element is pused on the stack, the index will actually refer to the previous stack (or -1 for the first one). So a good code fragment should error on that.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation is easy to understand and follow.

Comment: Regarding "the index will actually refer to the previous stack (or -1 for the first one)": it's important to note that when you call `push()`, `sizes[stackNum]` is incremented right before calling `indexOfTop()`. So, for example, when you push a value on the empty first array, the value returned by `indexOfTop()` will be `0`, not `-1`, because `sizes[0] == 1`. I personally found this code quite counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation pre-allocates all N stacks to capacity. Therefore, each stack has fixed offset inside the big array.

The offset of the initial element is computed as stack number (zero-based) times the fixed stack capacity. All you need to do now to find the index of the top element is adding the number of elements stored on the stack to the offset of the initial element.